# Getting KeyError when setting dataset column to variable with pandas

Tags: python, keyerror

I am attempting to set a dataset column (imported from csv) to a new variable in order to plot data in a histogram:

```
x = gcbs[gcbs['E1']]   #dataset is gcbs, column is 'E1'

plt.hist(x, bins = 9)
```

I receive the following error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([...,\n dtype='int64', length=2495)] are in the [columns]"
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Better to post code related to how you create the df, and a sample data as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use filtering with a boolean-mask, you need to use `loc`, and if you just want a column you get it by using `[]` e.g

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3,4],"y":[10,20,30,40]})
x = df["x"] #get the column "x"

df_gt_2 = df.loc[df["x"]>2] #Get the rows where "x" is greather than 2
```

so if I read your question correctly you just need to do the first part

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = gcbs["x"]
plt.hist(x,bins=9)
```